# error printing in mint

Tags: linux-mint, printer

I have installed mint 13 xfce on my parents desktop. I installed the hp psc 500 printer correctly and the first test page was printed perfectly. However, when they want to print a document now, there is an error that something went wrong.
I mailed the error reports to myself:

1: https://db.tt/c8eUDt08

2: http://pastebin.com/Viwa7FJ5

I don't understand what is in those 2 documents. 
Can you guys help me fix this?

edit: the output from `sudo service cups status` is: `cups start/running. process 638.`

Comment: The output would seem to be CUPS related. Are you using CUPS?

Comment: I truly don't know. I am still new to Linux and do not know much yet about it. I will search for what cups is and see if I can fix this at my parents computer. Can I simply install cups?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output of `sudo service cups status`. Better yet, try running `sudo service cups start` and then printing again.

Comment: In synaptic, there was an exclamation mark at 'cups'.

Comment: starting cups service again and then print again does not solve the problem. What else can I do?

Comment: My father told me he got an error message. The translation of this error is something like this: the server does not export any printer